# Trigonometric functions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, trigonometry

I have a data.frame which contain a series of values, Xg, to which I am applying trigonometric functions to create a new column in the data.frame called "angle":

```
dt$angle <- sin(asin(dt$Xg / 9.8))
dt$angle <- asin(dt$angle)
```

However when I apply the second line of code here it's not giving me the correct values, which I can work out using a calculator that are wrong.
Is this code applying the arcsine function to each data point individually or am I missing something?

Comment: are you confusing radians and degrees?  What happens if you multiply the result by `180/pi` ?  Can you please give us a reproducible question (i.e. show us some actual numbers, show us what you got, tell us what you expected to get ...)

Comment: I agree with Ben.  I highly doubt the functions are wrong - you're more likely just misunderstanding what the expected input is and what the output represents.  Take a look at `?asin` for more information.

Comment: Thankyou Ben, that is precisely what I was doing. Can't believe I missed that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I checked my arcsine function using the identity `tan(asin(x))=x/sqrt(1-x^2)`

```
x=seq(.1,.9,.001)
cbind(
tan(asin(x)),
x/sqrt(1-x^2))


            [,1]      [,2]
  [1,] 0.1005038 0.1005038
  [2,] 0.1015191 0.1015191
  [3,] 0.1025348 0.1025348
  [4,] 0.1035507 0.1035507
  [5,] 0.1045670 0.1045670
  [6,] 0.1055836 0.1055836
  [7,] 0.1066006 0.1066006
  [8,] 0.1076178 0.1076178
  [9,] 0.1086354 0.1086354
 [10,] 0.1096533 0.1096533
 [11,] 0.1106716 0.1106716
         ...
```

which looked pretty good to me. Try it and see if you get the same. Then check your calculator. Good Luck